# Is this wrapper I created for sql queries safe?

Tags: typescript, sqlite

I am trying to create a wrapper for a small sqlite, I know it is against sql to create dynamic queries but I would like to know if this is safe

```
async create(item: T): Promise<sqlite3.RunResult> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-parameter-reassignment
    const values = Object.keys(item).map(_ => _ = '?').join(', ');
    const query = `INSERT INTO ${this.table} VALUES (${values})`;
    const stmt = await this.database.prepare(query);

    return stmt.run(item);
}
```

So basically I call the class which has this function with a table name of my choice (in the code), the user enters object property values and I read the keys of the said object, then I create the query using the table name I choose and the placeholder values are generated from the object, is this safe?

Comment: Side note, you can avoid that `map` call: `const values = ",?".repeat(Object.keys().length).substring(1);` (and don't worry that it uses `.substring(1)` on an empty string if `Object.keys` returns an empty array, `"".substring(1)` is `""`).

Comment: thank you, that's a really nice solution to something I was wondering as well

Comment: Or, with `map`, the assignment is unecessary: `const values = Object.keys(item).map(_ => '?').join(', ')`.

Comment: For your question, the answer is yes, your code is safe.

Comment: A notice: you have to be sure of `this.table`. If this parameter comes from a frontend for example, it's not safe.

Comment: I call the class with the table name in my code, so I was aware, thanks :)